# Is it possible to configure Grails to never change a domain object unless .save() is called?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to configure Grails to that changes to domain objects are **never** persisted unless `.save()` is explicitly called?

I'm aware of `.read()`, but I'm looking for a general solution that would disable dirty-checking globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an perfect solution for your question. Referring to [this issue discussion](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4344), Disabling dirty-checking is impossible without interfering to Hibernate basic workings. Personally, I don't think it worth the risks.